# Tomcat Memory leak (Some old war already in memory)

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, memory-leaks

The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their
classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory
leak

its shows number of war files are still in memory.,Is there any option so that we can delete it?

Comment: Version of your Tomcat?

Comment: @HannoBinder---Apache Tomcat/7.0.59

Answer (score 0):

Just add this dependency classloader-leak-prevention.jar in your build path. It will resolved your problem.
If you are using maven project then just add this dependency.

```
<!-- For Classloader leak protection -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>se.jiderhamn</groupId>
        <artifactId>classloader-leak-prevention</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```